# Only last line written appears in output file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know A lot of people ask about that but I tried a lot of method and none of it work for me.

I'm writing random string generator using python but when I save it to text file it only contains the last line.

But in command line its print all lines.

This is my code.

```
import sys
import random

    
ch = 'ZXCVBNM<>?":LKJHGFDSAQWERTYUIOP{}|+_)(*&^%$#@!~zxcvbnm,./;lkjhgfdsapoiuytrewq`1234567890'

nop = input('How Many password do you want to create?')
nop = int(nop)

lop = input('Whats the length of passwords?')
lop = int(lop)

for p in range (nop):
    password = ''
    for l in range(lop):
       password += random.choice(ch)
    print(password)
    pwd = open("pwd.txt", "w")
    pwd.write(password)
    pwd.close()
```

Comment: Opening a file with `w` mode erases the existing contents.  And you're doing that inside the loop, so each time through the loop, it erases all the previous contents.  Move the `open()` to before the loop, and move the `close()` after.

Comment: Opening a file in write mode overwrites its data. Move the line `pwd = open("pwd.txt", "w")` outside of the nested loops, and close the file only when you're done.

Comment: Also you'll probably want to to write a newline after each password, or else all the passwords will be joined together on one line.

Answer (score 2):

because you are opening the file for writing for each password.  Put your `open()` before `for p in range(nop)` and put your `close()` after that loop has completed.  (Outdent it.)

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the password as part of the for loop, so the file is getting rewritten on every line.

You probably want this

```
for p in range (nop):
   password = ''
   for l in range(lop):
      password += random.choice(ch)
print(password)
pwd = open("pwd.txt", "w")
pwd.write(password)
pwd.close()
```